# Galois group of $X^5-1\in\mathbb F_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to find the Galois group of $X^5-1$ over the finite field $\mathbb F_7$ but I don't know how to find Galois groups over finite fields.

Over $\mathbb Q$ the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)/\mathbb Q)$ would be isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
Prove first that $x^5-1$ splits as 
$$ (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1) $$
over $\mathbb{F}_7$, since $\Phi_5(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_7$. This happens because the order of $7\pmod{5}$ is four, hence there are no elements with order five in $\mathbb{F}_7^*,\mathbb{F}_{49}^*$ or $\mathbb{F}_{343}^*$, while in $\mathbb{F}_{7^4}^*$ there is an element of order five by Cauchy's theorem for groups, since $ 5\mid(7^4-1)$. At last, notice that the Galois group of an irreducible cyclotomic polynomial is always a cyclic group.

Comment: So the Galois group is given by $\langle\zeta_5\rangle$?

Comment: Or use the fact that any extension of finite fields has cyclic Galois group, generated by the appropriate Frobenius.